# p:datatable alignment prime faces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a problem with p:table alignment below is the picture(picture one) when first time load this p:table using p:commandbutton if i click on scenario Two tab and click back to scenario One tab i get right alignment of table see picture two.

picture one
[image]

picture two 
[image]

this is the button when i click first time, table loads

```
<p:commandButton id="isFinancialYearSubmitId" value="submit" update="panelGridId scenarioTabViewId:budgetAnalysisDataTableId scenarioTabViewId:selectColumnId scenarioTabViewId:isApprovedBooleanId_checkBox " action="#{budgetAnalysisAction.isFinancialYearOpened}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args); isFinancialYearOpenedOnComplete('analysisTheBudgetForm');"/>
```

and this is table

```
<p:dataTable id="budgetAnalysisDataTableId"
rowIndexVar="index" editable="true"
resizableColumns="true"
value="#{budgetAnalysisAction.budgetScenarioHescoProposalBean.budgetScenarioHescoProposalListBean}"
var="budgetScenarioHescoProposalList"
scrollWidth="800" scrollHeight="250" scrollable="true"
>
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" process=":analysisTheBudgetForm:scenarioTabViewId:scenarioOneId_tab :analysisTheBudgetForm:scenarioTabViewId:isApprovedBooleanId_checkBox :analysisTheBudgetForm:scenarioTabViewId:budgetAnalysisDataTableId" listener="#{budgetAnalysisAction.analysisTheBudgetRowEditOnAjax}" />

<p:column headerText="Edit" width="20">
<p:rowEditor />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Sub Head Of Accounts" width="150">
<h:outputText value="#{index}" />
<h:outputText value="#{budgetScenarioHescoProposalList.budgetSubHeadOfAccountsBean.subHeadOfAccountNameBean}" />
</p:column>

<p:column width="60">
// 11 other columns with same width(width="60") but different data. 
</p:column>
```

this is an inspect element of picture one

[image]

this is an inspect element of picture two

[image]

Comment: Is this happening in a particular browser or in all?

Comment: @SRy in IE9, chrome , firefox

Comment: Clearly a PrimeFaces bug. Report it to PrimeFaces guys.

Comment: @BalusC i have posted this issue. can you tell me another way to resolve this ?

Comment: @BalusC i ve changed 3.5 to 4.0, it seems there is also ajax tab change bug i need 3.5.x can you guide me from where can i get this ?